# I can't access a <div> tag by using the getElementsByClassName method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to learn how to manipulate elements in DOM.
So I have this HTML code under the `<body>` tag:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>This is a sample website</p>
</div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

And this is its JS code:

```
var contento = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
contento.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Bienvenida";
```

What I tried so far:
In my HTML code, I tried to change div's class attribute to id attribute and then I changed the getElementsByClassName to getElementById in my JS code. It worked like a charm. But I want to know why it's not working if I'm using the class attribute?

Is it not supported by the DIV tag?
Then why is it being used in this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

Comment: contento is not the element, but a list of elements. Have you tried `contento [0]`?

Comment: Use `document.querySelector(".content h1")` So much shorter and cleaner.

Comment: ...and change it to `querySelectorAll` if you need multiple that have the same positional relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'getElementsByClassName' acts just like 'getElementsByTagName' so it returns an array of all the elements that have the class you specified

You may for example have three elements that have that class so depending on which one you want to target you should target it with the array index that corresponds to it's DOM order -1 ;)

There you go :)

```
var contento = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
contento.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Bienvenida";
```

> **EDIT :** Added code snippet

```js
var contento = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
contento.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Bienvenida";
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>This is a sample website</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `.getElementsByClassName` returns a node list not a single node

Try to do `document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];` (assuming there is only one and thats the one you want)